# Robot Web Tools – data not loading

Tags: ros, rosbridge, robotwebtools, web

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to see any of the [robot web tools demos](http://robotwebtools.org/demos.html) – I can manipulate the area (seeing the coordinate frame rotate when I click and drag) but no models nor maps show up. I don't receive any error messages in console.

Has anyone experienced the same problem or have any idea what the solution is? Thanks!

Edit: removed one of the two problems I'd experienced (was simply a path issue).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/117746/robot-web-tools-%E2%80%93-data-not-loading/) by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2014-01-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2014-01-14**:
As for my specs: I'm using a retina MacBook Pro and connecting to both the demos through Chrome (though I've tried Firefox as well, to no success).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like the demo ROS servers we are running went down. I will investigate!

---

Originally posted by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) with karma: 1173 on 2014-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on 2014-01-15**:
Back up and running!

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2014-01-15**:
Awesome, thank you!